# VirtualBox under Archlinux can't connect to Internet after "pacman -Syu"

Tags: arch-linux, virtualbox

I have a windows 7 VM in virtualbox and I'm used to connect the Internet though **NAT**.
But after the last system upgrade, the Internet can't be reached in the VM.

I check the log at `/var/log/pacman.log` and find this:

```
[2013-04-16 16:03] [ALPM-SCRIPTLET] In order to use the new version, reload all virtualbox modules manually.
[2013-04-16 16:03] [PACMAN] upgraded virtualbox-host-modules (4.2.10-4 -> 4.2.12-1)
[2013-04-16 16:03] [PACMAN] upgraded virtualbox (4.2.10-2 -> 4.2.12-1)
[2013-04-16 16:04] [PACMAN] upgraded virtualbox-guest-iso (4.2.10-1 -> 4.2.12-1)
```

I don't know its exact meaning but after browsing some wiki I tried to edit `/etc/modules-load.d/virtualbox-modules.conf`:

```
vboxdrv
vboxsf
vboxvideo
vboxguest
```

I also tried `modprobe vboxdrv` in CLI. All turned out to be of no use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this wiki page in the Arch project's wiki:

- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Automatic_re-compilation_of_the_virtualbox_host_modules_with_every_update_of_any_kernel

I think you may need to run this command to get virtualbox up to date:

```
% pacman -Sy linux-headers && pacman -Su
```

Comment: Problem solved,thank you!I haven't read the wiki very carefully...